Recomposition on unrelated state changes
Why does recomposition happen to composables when state changes on Flows that are unrelated to the data going into that specific composable. if i remove loadingState and componentState then composition happens only once. But with them both collecting then Component3 recomps 7-8 times. The scope of Component3 is using only componentStateTest to populate its data. I dont understand why its recomposing so many times when the fields that get updated are not even passed or used by Component3.
Update: I do notice that its only the parent of each component that gets recomposed, and the child layouts and do not get recomposed. Still would like to know if this is expected behaviour or if there is possible performance improvements i can do.
val loadingState by viewModel.loadingState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
val componentState by viewModel.componentState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
// this was created to test if recomp happens less
val componentStateTest = viewModel.userPointsBlockModel.collectAsStateWithLifecycle() 

val pullRefreshState =
    rememberPullRefreshState(
        refreshing = loadingState,
        onRefresh = { viewModel.refreshData(true) },
    )

Box(
    modifier =
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(colors.contentColor)
            .pullRefresh(pullRefreshState),
        ) {
            LazyColumn(
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 24.dp),
            ) {
                item {
                    Component1(componentState, viewModel)
                    Component2(componentState)
                    Component3(componentStateTest, viewModel)
                }

                PullRefreshIndicator(
                    refreshing = loadingState,
                    state = pullRefreshState,
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter),
                    backgroundColor = if (loadingState) colors.color1 else colors.color2,
                )
            }
        }

